# R expand() function does not take variable list

Tags: r, combinations, expand

I am trying to use expand() function to create combinations of multiple variables in the list vector. The following codes correctly produces 27 rows of combinations when the atomic vectors are listed. However, when I try to use the var_list in many different forms, it the expand() function does not produce desired outcome of 27 combinations. How could I use the var_list to dynamically create combinations of multiple columns in a data frame df?

```
abc <- letters[1:3]
num <- c(1,2,3)
xyz <- letters[24:26]
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(abc,num,xyz))         
combinations_1 <- expand(df,abc,num,xyz)   #This returns 27 combinations

var_list <- c("abc","num","xyz")
combinations_2 <- expand(df,var_list)      #This returns 3 combinations
combinations_3 <- expand(df,df[var_list])  #This returns 3 combinations
combinations_4 <- expand(df,noquote(var_list))  #This returns 3 combinations
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mget` to return the values of the object names

```
expand.grid(mget(var_list))
```

Or if we need to make use of 'df', just extract with `[`

```
expand.grid(df[var_list])
```

---

Or using `expand`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
expand(df, !!! rlang::syms(var_list))
# A tibble: 27 x 3
#   abc   num   xyz  
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>
# 1 a     1     x    
# 2 a     1     y    
# 3 a     1     z    
# 4 a     2     x    
# 5 a     2     y    
# 6 a     2     z    
# 7 a     3     x    
# 8 a     3     y    
# 9 a     3     z    
#10 b     1     x    
# … with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Both solutions work beautifully! One follow-up question on expand.grid(mget(var_list)) approach. Where and how do you specify the data.frame from which the var_list is defined? Although it works fine in the simple example above, when I tried the approach in my main code, R complains that the variables are not found. Thanks.

Comment: @Joseph I think you just need `expand.grid(df[var_list])`

Answer (score 1):

You can make `var_list` a list of symbols and splice.

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  expand(!!!syms(var_list))

# A tibble: 27 x 3
   abc   num   xyz  
   <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1 a     1     x    
 2 a     1     y    
 3 a     1     z    
 4 a     2     x    
 5 a     2     y    
 6 a     2     z    
 7 a     3     x    
 8 a     3     y    
 9 a     3     z    
10 b     1     x    
# ... with 17 more rows
```